# ExtJS - How to customize buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, extjs4

I need to create some custom buttons - like a red button with white text, green button with white text, etc.

I followed the accepted answer of the same question "[How to change background of hovered and pressed extjs-button dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118487/282855)" but did not work for me. It just changes the ui without any interactions. When I click the customized button, it toggles despite the handler function is executed.

ExtJS button has 2 configuration for styling according to documentation: `overCls` and `pressedCls`. Despite I set them both `pressedCls` configuration did not work for me.

Which css properties should I override/define in order to create my own buttons?

Sencha Fiddle Link: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/fim

Answer (score 7, accepted):

simply, every form component has a property called "cls". So you can use the following:

```
cls: 'myclass'
```

Edit for the last issue:

You have to override the x-btn-focus class, to remove/replace the blue background color:

```
.x-btn-focus.green-button { 
  background:#46a546;
}
```

Edit of your your fiddle's css:

```
.green-button{
    background:#46a546;
    border: none;!important;
    color: #ffffff;!important;
}

.green-button .x-btn-inner {
    color: #ffffff;
}


.green-button-over {
    background: #4cc54c;
    border: none;
}


.x-btn-over.green-button {
    background: #4cc54c;
    border-color: #4cc54c;
}

.x-btn-pressed.green-button {
    background: #5b9f5b;
    border-color: #5b9f5b;
}
.x-btn-focus.green-button { 
  background:#46a546;
}
```

Comment: thanks; but this just changes static ui of button; I need to change `over` and `pressed` ui too. I added the sencha fiddle link to the post; you can see in action what I mean.

Comment: It seems working in your fiddle. The button is green, on hover it's light green, on mousedown it's blue...

Comment: no it is not; when the button is clicked the button color is become dark blue. And it toggles; does not turn to the original color after the click event. When you click somewhere outside of the button, then it turns to the original color which is green. It should be like this: A **green** button; on over it should become **light green** and when it is clicked it should be **dark green**. thanks for your care.

Comment: it is still blue on over.

Comment: Replace the css with the posted above. It works 100%. I can't save your fiddle so you have to setup it manually.

Comment: replaced; everything is perfect except on press. The background becomes blue when the button is clicked.

Comment: Which browser are you using? It works on Firefox and Internet Explorer like a charm. I checked your updated fiddle. The button has now light green (like the hover effect) if button is clicked.

Comment: it is same on both Chrome & Firefox. Due to I work on Linux; did not test on IE yet.

Comment: there is only one issue still exists; the button toggles even click is finished. Fiddle is updated.

Comment: So, i don't see the issue here. It turns now into yellow background. If you click on the button, the focus class is set to it, because your button now owns the focus. If you want the button looks like the default one, you have to override the focus class with the same css like the default button css. (i used the same green background in my example for the focus class)

Comment: thanks a lot for your help; now it works as expected!

Answer (score 1):

Try using these css classes :

```
.x-btn-over.green-button
```

and

```
.x-btn-pressed.green-button
```

I don't know if this is preferable to defining and using a custom UI but it's a quick fix.

Hope it helps

Pedro

EDIT (adding css as in comment below)

```
.x-btn-over.green-button {
    background: #4cc54c;
    background-color: red !important;
    background-image: none;
}
.x-btn-pressed.green-button {
    background: yellow;
    background-color:yellow !important;
    border:solid 1px red !important;
}
```

Added some random properties you might need `background-image`, etc

Comment: unfortunately did not work for me. do you have a chance to look the fiddle I created for it: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/fim

Comment: I believe the problem is in the CSS itself, sometimes, to properly override a css property, you need to add !important at the end, before the semicolon. ---

.x-btn-over.green-button {
    background: #4cc54c;
    background-color: red !important;
    background-image: none;
}

.x-btn-pressed.green-button {
    background: yellow;
    background-color:yellow !important;
    border:solid 1px red !important;
    
} --- Cant really format a comment, will try to add these to my answer, tested on your fiddle and they seem to be working.

Comment: thanks for your care; everything is perfect except on press. The background becomes blue when the button is clicked.

Comment: Try adding --- background-image: none !important; ---- to the x-btn-pressed class

Comment: ok now there is no blue color at anywhere; but still button toggles despite click event is finished!?

Comment: `.x-btn-focus.green-button { 
  background:#46a546;
}` is required to turn the button's color to back after click as @Tyr suggested

Comment: Was going to suggest just that. No point in repeating so i'll just +1.

Answer (score 0):

Following CSS works for me:

```
.numpad-btn {
    background: #008080 !important;
}

.numpad-btn .x-btn-inner {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.x-btn-over.numpad-btn {
    background: #00baba;
    border: solid 1px #00baba !important;
    background-color: #00baba !important;
    background-image: none;
}

.x-btn-pressed.numpad-btn {
    background: #005151;
    background-color: #005151 !important;
    border: solid 1px #005151 !important;
    background-image: none !important;
}

.x-btn-focus.numpad-btn {
    background: #008080;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question was related to ExtJS 4, but I wanted to add a solution for those that find this page but want to use ExtJS 6.

In ExtJS 6, you can create a custom theme using Sass that will result in the required CSS classes being generated for you. A tutorial for this can be found here: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/guides/core_concepts/theming.html

As a simple example, this Sass snippet (after being processed by Sencha Cmd) results in the various CSS classes required for a red button. Note that the $ui attribute becomes the name you reference this style by.

```
@include extjs-button-small-ui(
  $ui: 'red',
  $background-color: red,
  $border-color: red,
  $color: #fff
);
```

You configure a component to use these classes via the 'ui' config attribute. For example:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    itemId: 'deleteBtn',
    ui: 'red',
    width: 180,
    text: 'Delete',
    tooltip: 'Delete this item',
    handler: 'onDeleteClick'
}
```